# Images no longer shows after uninstalling a React Native package

Tags: image, react-native, npm

In my React-Native App I have several screens with different images and background images. I just proceeded to do the following:

`npm uninstall --save react-native-simple-radio-button`

This also alerted me that there was an npm update. So I ran:

`npm install -g npm`

My images are no longer showing up. I made no other changes to my code. I have shut down both the simulator and the terminal (on MacOS). As per normal, I run:

`react-native run-ios`

My apps work, but my `<Image>` and `<ImageBackground>` elements no longer show the image. Backgrounds all show a white screen now. Where images are supposed to be there is an empty space big enough for the image to go.

Examples of related image code look like this:

`<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/pic001.jpg')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', flex: 1}}>`

and:

`<Image source={require('../assets/images/logo4.png')} resizeMode={'contain'} style={{alignSelf: 'center', width: '90%', height: '85%'}} />`

What has stopped my images from showing up?

**Update**

I have tried again. It does indeed seem to be the removal of the package `react-native-simple-radio-button` that is causing me grief. I ran another test based on a backup I had. Below are some of the more technical details as to what might have changed. The directory `MyApp02-bad/node_modules` is the directory before I ran the uninstall command. The `node_modules` in the current path is from after I ran the uninstall command.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:MyApp002 bobross$ npm uninstall --save react-native-simple-radio-button
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

removed 3 packages, updated 14 packages and audited 1110 packages in 6.72s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2688 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

and:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:MyApp002 bobross$ diff -qr node_modules/ ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/
Files node_modules/@react-native-community/eslint-config/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/@react-native-community/eslint-config/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/android: build
Files node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/package.json differ
Files node_modules/eslint/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/eslint/package.json differ
Files node_modules/jest/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/jest/package.json differ
Files node_modules/react/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release: .gitignore
Only in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release: .npmignore
Files node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m differ
Files node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/systeminfo/AndroidInfoModule.java and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/systeminfo/AndroidInfoModule.java differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/hermes/inspector/tools/msggen: .gitignore
Only in node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/hermes/inspector/tools/msggen: .npmignore
Files node_modules/react-native/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android: build
Files node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android: build
Files node_modules/react-native-reanimated/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android: build
Files node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-screens/android: build
Files node_modules/react-native-screens/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-screens/package.json differ
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/: react-native-simple-radio-button
Only in ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-sound/android: build
Files node_modules/react-native-sound/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-native-sound/package.json differ
Files node_modules/react-navigation/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-navigation/package.json differ
Files node_modules/react-navigation-stack/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-navigation-stack/package.json differ
Files node_modules/react-test-renderer/package.json and ../MyApp002-bad/node_modules/react-test-renderer/package.json differ
```

**My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: version of RN ? if you are using a simulator with ios 14 there is a bug with images

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz I am using `RN 0.61.5`. The default simulator seems to be set to `iPhone 11 (iOS 14.2)`. However, why were images working before? I assume the iOS version never changed. What about removing this package causes this to happen?

Comment: maybe you run in old ios version or you update xcode try use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fix-image or read https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz Nope. Because I can still go back to a backup of the project and it works just fine using the same ios version and xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem regarding the ios 14.

```
    npm i -g patch-package
patch-package
```

add following code in your `package.json` inside `scripts` :

```
scripts:{
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

That might fix your problem.

Comment: So, why do images work properly until I uninstall the react-native-simple-radio-button package?

Comment: Its issue regarding ios 14 nd related to Xcode new update i guess.i have same problem but it is working now